# in oracle query, select only few columns with union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables something like this:

TABLE_1:

`COL_A (int), COL_B (float), COL_C (float)`

and

TABLE_2:

`COL_A (int), COL_B (varchar), COL_C (varchar)`

My query is using a UNION to get only COL_A(int) from table 2 like

```
SELECT COL_A, COL_B, COL_C FROM table1 UNION 
SELECT COL_A               FROM table2
```

It's throwing an error. How do we get the results?

Comment: In the event you are not aware I am only making sure that you know the difference between UNION vs UNION ALL.  UNION will remove duplicate rows FYI.  If that is your expectation than that is just fine.  As long as it is known.

Comment: In Relational DBMS each result set is a set of tuples (rows) of exactly the same structure (number and type of columns)

Answer (score 5):

All subquery members of a `UNION` must have the same number and types of columns. In your case the first subquery has three columns, but the second one has only one.

Solution: pad the second subquery with nulls.

For example:

```
select COL_A, COL_B, COL_C from table1
union 
select COL_A, null, null from table2
```